# Sitefinity login failure: "Incorrect Username/Password Combination"

Tags: asp.net, sitefinity, sitefinity-4

I have a Sitefinity app that just won't let me log in.

I've checked:

1. Event viewer, no errors.
2. Sitefinity log files, nothing.
3. Database - I tried logging in a multitude of times yet it's not even locking the account out.
4. Checked to make sure the `DataConfig` points to the correct database.

What could be another reason for it not letting me log in.

Thanks,
Jacques

Comment: Are you talking about the Sitefinity Website Administrator backend? Or a custom Sitefinity app with it's own custom login that you built yourself?

Comment: Sitefinity website backend yes

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, Jacques, and I found that examining the control's properties during the LoginError event showed other errors besides the "Incorrect..." error. Wire up the control's LoginError event and set a breakpoint:

```
//In Page_Load:
YourControl.LoginError += new EventHandler(YourControl_LoginError);    

void YourControl_LoginError(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //Set a breakpoint here
}
```

...The Control's .FailureText may say "Incorrect UserName/Password Combination", but if you examine the control's .FailureTextControl.Text, It may have a more specific message.

I hope this gets you started... FWIW, in my case, the problem was that setting the DenyLogonMessageText and Orientation attributes in the markup for the control causes a silent error.

Comment: Thanks for the input DShultz,

I've added a control to a dummy page and attached to the LoginError event. It's definitely hitting the error event, but I've done a FindControl for the FailureTextControl and it doesn't find anything. How do I find the FailureTextControl?

Comment: It's not very well named, but FailureTextControl is actually just a property on your login control: LoginControl.FailureTextControl.Text as opposed to LoginControl.FailureText. (SF 4.1 SP 1)